# escape any string from database to store in HTML id attribute that is readable with jQuery

Tags: jquery, database, escaping, html

I'm making a custom sorting tool for my custom gridview.

I use jQuery ui `$.autocomplete()` to find `DISTINCT` `VALUE`s from a `COLUMN` in a `TABLE`.

I then add the selected values to a jquery ui `$.selectable()`.

I usually use the `id` attribute to store distinct type values like this (such as `TABLE` `PRIMARY`ies), so my problem comes in when I try to store these values where they probably will not be compliant with HTML `id` standards or readable by jQuery.

How can I create a function to escape and de-escape any text from a database into HTML `id` readable by jQuery and back again?

Comment: Why store these as an id?  Why not use `.data()` where you can store any string or javascript data type with no restrictions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store custom attributes on any HTML object with the `data-` prefix as per the HTML5 spec (which is backwardly compatible with earlier versions of HTML too).  These can be used in selector queries (the same way any attribute is used in a query) or can be retrieved with jQuery's `.data()`.  There are still a few restrictions on the characters that can be in a custom attribute like quoting, but it is less restrictive than an id value.

Answer (score 2):

To do the encoding/decoding, you can use the functions described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7124052/2165552)

To do a jquery lookup you can use `$('[id="' + escapedId + '"]');`. It's not the most efficient, but it will guarantee that none of your special characters will be mistaken for part of the selector.

Comment: Note: do not prefix the id value with a `#`.